# WSDL Response with Camel and CXF

Tags: wsdl, cxf, apache-camel, wsdl2java

Although I've interacted with them for years I'm very new to WSDL design. I have a WSDL that I'm trying to use with Camel & CXF generating the code using wsdl2java.

What I'm trying to achieve is a custom response string to the SOAP client and convert the SOAP request to JSON and push it to a websockets endpoint.

My WSDL schema generates the response classes when the code is generated, but the response never seems to  be called in the debugger.

Whats more, if I remove the json converter in Camel the whole soap request is returned to the SOAP client, if I leave my converter in, it then gets upset because its expecting XML and it gets a json blob.

```
 <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="position-ws"
                 address="/positions"
                 endpointName="c:PositionsPort"
                 serviceName="c:PositionsService"
                 serviceClass="com.company.finance.positions.PositionsImpl"
                 xmlns:c="http://positions.finance.company.com/">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true"></entry>
    </cxf:properties>
                 </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <dataFormats>
        <xmljson id="xmljson"/>
        <xmljson id="xmljsonWithOptions" forceTopLevelObject="true" trimSpaces="true" rootName="newRoot" skipNamespaces="true"
                 removeNamespacePrefixes="true" expandableProperties="d e"/>
    </dataFormats>

    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:position-ws?dataFormat=PAYLOAD"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="String"></convertBodyTo>
        <to uri="log:com.mycompany.order?level=DEBUG"/>
        <process ref="xmlTransformProcessor"/>
        <to uri="log:com.mycompany.order?level=DEBUG"/>
        <to uri="websocket:positionsTopic?sendToAll=true"/>

    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="xmlTransformProcessor" class="com.company.finance.positions.XMLTransformer"/>
```

**XML to Json Converter**

```
public class XMLTransformer implements Processor {

public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);


    JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(data);
    String json = jsonObj.toString();

    // use regular java code to transform to a better form
    //exchange.getIn().setBody(json);
    exchange.getOut().setBody(json);
}

}
```

So my question is, using Camel, how do I return a custom response String "Okay", "Not Okay" etc whilst pushing the rest of the data to another step in the route?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.

I needed something like:

```
 <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:position-ws"/>
        <to uri="log:com.mycompany.order?level=DEBUG"/>
        <convertBodyTo type="com.company.finance.positions.PositionSummary"/>
        <marshal>
        <jaxb contextPath="com.meteoriteconsulting.finance.positions"
        partClass="com.company.finance.positions.NewEntry"
        fragment="true"
        partNamespace="{http://com.company}NewEntry" />
        </marshal>
        <process ref="xmlTransformProcessor"/>
        <to uri="log:com.mycompany.order?level=DEBUG"/>
        <to uri="websocket:positionsTopic?sendToAll=true"/>
        <transform>
            <constant>OK</constant>
        </transform>

    </route>
```